# Reduced performance when creating object in classic asp

Tags: performance, optimization, asp-classic

Trying to measure a website performance I created a simple logging `sub` to see what parts are slow during the execution of a classic asp page.

```
sub log(logText)
    dim fs, f
    set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set f = fs.OpenTextFile("log.txt", 8, true)
    f.WriteLine(now() & " - " & logText)
    f.Close
    set f = Nothing
    set fs = Nothing
end sub

log "Loading client countries"
set myR = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
myR.ActiveConnection = aConnection
myR.CursorLocation=2
myR.CursorType=3
myR.LockType=2
myR.Source = "SELECT * FROM CC ORDER BY ccName ASC"
log "Opening db connection"
myR.open()
log "Opened db connection"
```

Here are the results (only showing the time part):

```
...
11:13:01 - Loading client countries
11:13:06 - Opening db connection
11:13:06 - Opened db connection
...
```

Creating the `ADODBRecordSet` and setting a few properties takes about 5 seconds. This does not always happen, sometimes the code is executed fast, but usually when I reload the page 
after a few minutes the loading times are more or less the same as the example's. Could this really be a server/resources issue or should I consider rewriting the code? (My best option would be to write this in `C#`, but I have to study this code first before moving forward anyway).

***Update***: I added more code after receiving 1st comment to present a few more code. Explanation: The code creates a `combobox` (selection menu) with the retrieved countries (it continues where the previous piece of code stopped).

```
if not myR.eof then
    clientCountries = myR.getrows
    send("<option value='0'>Select country</option>")
    log "Creating combobox options"
    for i = 0 to ubound(clientCountries, 2)
        if cstr(session("clientCountry")) <> "" then
            if cstr(clientCountries(1, i)) = cstr(session("clientCountry")) then
                isSelected = "selected" else isSelected = ""
            end if
        end if
        if cstr(session("clientCountry")) = "" then
            if cstr(clientCountries(1, i)) = "23" then
                isSelected = "selected"
            else
                isSelected = ""
            end if
        end if
        optionString = ""
        optionString = clientCountries(2, i)
        send("<option value='" & clientCountries(1, i) & "' " & isSelected & ">" & convertToProperCase(optionString) & "</option>")
    next
    log "Created combobox options"
end if
myR.Close
myR.ActiveConnection.close
myR.ActiveConnection = nothing
set myR = nothing
log "Loaded client countries"
```

The next two log entries are as follows:

```
11:13:06 - Creating combobox options
11:13:06 - Created combobox options
...
```

So far, the `SELECT` query as the rest of the page (2 or 3 queries more) is executed within the next second more or less. The only part slowing the page down is what you can see in the first part of the log. I'm not sure if I can profile the ***SQLServer***, because I only have ***cPanel*** access. This is the only way I know of, unless there's something else I could have a look at.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the SQL server yet? I'd try it just to see how long your select really took.

Comment: @NathanRice I have updated the question with more information, thanks for taking a look anyway.

Comment: How long is it taking (as a guess)? Something like this shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: A minor improvement: You should only have one IF statement in the FOR loop. Swap them around and use an ELSE instead of a second IF.

Comment: @BlueSix Unfortunately, miliseconds are not possible to get through classic asp from what I've researched so far.

Comment: @BlueSix also, thanks for the improvement, but my priority is to fix this issue first, then move on to clean up the code. Trust me, there are much much worse things in there. Example: connection strings copied in 1000+ places...

Comment: Wasn't the issue to speed things up? That's what I was offering. Have you profiled the SQL in SQLServer to ensure that's not a bottleneck?

Comment: @BlueSix I cannot profile the `SQLServer`. However, if you read closely the log file, you can see that, my main concern at this point is the speed before opening the `RecordSet`

Comment: What does your connection string look like and which provider are you using?

Comment: Opening & writing to a text file every time you want to log something is a bad way to log. Store your logging messages in memory and write them to the file after the whole procedure has finished. Accessing the file system is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

First, Check your connection string, I've experienced slower times with certain providers. The best provider I've found for classic asp is `sqloledb`

Second, I would close my SQL object before I did the `For` statement on the GetRows() array.  You don't want to keep that open if you don't need to.

Third, I'd use stored procedures. You'll get a performance improvement by saving on compile time.

Fourth, I would avoid doing a `SELECT *` statement at all cost, instead I would return ONLY the columns I need.  (Your code looks like it only needs 2 columns)

Fifth, I would build indexes on the tables taking longer than expected.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, I would consider other languages/solutions.  Not sure what the dataset looks like, so can't say if a flat-file database should be considered or not.

Also, try this for a recordset instead and see what happens:

```
Set myR = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
myR.Open "SELECT * FROM CC ORDER BY ccName ASC", aConnection
If myR.RecordCount > 0 Then clientCountries = myR.GetRows()
myR.Close
Set myR = Nothing

If IsArray(myR) Then
  For ....
```

Comment: The connectionString looks like this: `Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS;Database=*****;Uid=*****; Pwd=******;`

Comment: I have just quit this job, as I could not talk sense to the managers and show them the technical difficulties, but I still have access and can persuade them to let me fix this. However, what I would like to note is that my main concern was the time spent before opening the database, so I guess the connection provider makes sense. What I don't know is if I can use another provider, so I have to check if it's available or should be installed. Anyway, this will be resolved after all and will definitely try what you suggest, thanks!

Comment: Yea, you should try this provider, hasn't been to bad for me: `Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MyDB; User Id=***; Password=***;`

Comment: The newly hired programmer tried your solution but unfortunately the speed problem was not solved, so this looks even more like a server resources issue.